# jQuery on() variable as selector issue

Tags: jquery

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong and why this code works just fine:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-slider-next]', function() {
    slider('next');
});
```

while this breaks behaviour of a slider:

```
var $slider_next_btn = $('[data-slider-next]');
$(document).on('click', $slider_next_btn, function() {
    slider('next');
});
```

Context:

- First: http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/zenD2/;
- Second: http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/6FrSn/.

---

```
<div class="b-slider" data-slider>
    <div class="b-slider__arrow b-slider__arrow_l" data-slider-prev>←</div>
    <div class="b-slider__arrow b-slider__arrow_r" data-slider-next>→</div>
    <div data-slide data-content="1.1"></div>
    <div data-slide data-content="1.2"></div>
    <div data-slide data-content="1.3"></div>
</div>

// Slider function itself.
function slider( _direction ) {

    var $slide = $('[data-slide]'),
        $inactive = $('[data-slide]:not([data-slide-active])'),
        $active = $('[data-slide][data-slide-active]');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) var $active = $slide.first();

    var content = $active.attr('data-content');

    // Functions for loaded slider.
    if ( _direction == 'load') {
        $inactive.hide();
        $active.show()
        .text(content)
        .attr('data-slide-active', '');
    }

    // Functions for any slider button.
    else {
        $inactive.hide();

        // Functions for next slider button.
        if ( _direction == 'next') {
            var $next = $active.next('[data-slide]').length ? $active.next('[data-slide]')
            : $slide.first();
        }

        // Functions for prev. slider button.
        else if ( _direction == 'prev') {
            var $next = $active.prev('[data-slide]').length ? $active.prev('[data-slide]')
            : $slide.last();
        }

        // Functions for any slider action.
        $next.show()
        .text(content)
        .attr('data-slide-active', '');
        $active.hide().removeAttr('data-slide-active');
    }
}

// Slider loaded
$('[data-slider-next]').ready(function() {
    slider('load');
});

// & next button
var $slider_next_btn = $('[data-slider-next]');
$(document).on('click', $slider_next_btn, function() {
    slider('next');
});

// & prev. button
var $slider_prev_btn = $('[data-slider-prev]');
$(document).on('click', $slider_prev_btn, function() {
    slider('prev');
});
```

Comment: *"I can't understand what I'm doing wrong"* Well, you cannot substitute the selector with a jQuery object. And if you look at the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject), it's pretty clear: *"selector, string: A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event."*. A jQuery object is not a selector string. Also, if I think correctly what you are trying to do with that, then the solution is to just bind the event handler directly to the selected elements.

Comment: It makes no sense IMHO to even try and use it that way. If you want to bind an event to a selection of elements that you already have (and don’t need even delegation), then why not use `$slider_next_btn.on("click", handler)` (without a selector in this case) in the first place …?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot, `$slider_next_btn.on("click", handler)` is what I have to use. I would like to mark as the answer your comment If you could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense IMHO to even try and use it that way.

If you want to bind an event to a selection of elements that you already have (and don’t need even delegation), then you should use `$slider_next_btn.on("click", handlerFunction)` (without a selector in this case) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

> selector
>
> **Type: String**
>   A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

You're passing a reference to the jQuery object returned (with the variable use case). Update it to:

```
var $slider_next_btn = '[data-slider-next]';
$(document).on('click', $slider_next_btn, function() {
    slider('next');
});
```

And it'll work.

If you're caching the variable for use later in your code, you could update it to:

```
var $slider_next_btn = $('[data-slider-next]');
$(document).on('click', $slider_next_btn.selector, function() {
    slider('next');
});
```

And that would return the selector passed to jQuery for the element.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. However, @CBroe suggested a better way for my case: '$slider_next_btn.on("click", handler)'.

Comment: Hey, no worries! CBroe's answer is indeed correct for binding events directly. In the future, if you run into a use case where you want to cache the variable and use it in your code (second example) and access the selector, you'll know the way :) Thanks for the upvote!